# Java remove User defined object from Tree Set

Tags: java, treeset, user-defined

I have created a class of Patient object containing patient name and gender and I want to remove it base on Patient name. What is the correct way to do it?

This is my Patient object:

```
class Patient {

    private String name;
    private int gender;

    public Patient(String name, int gender){
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getGender(){
        return this.gender;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setGender(int gender){
        this.gender = gender;
    }

}
```

This is my Treeset declaration: `private TreeSet<Patient> ts = new TreeSet<Patient>(new nameComp());`

This is my remove method (I don't know how to start)

```
void RemovePatient(String patientName) {

}
```

Comment: Iterate through your treeset and find the one with the name you want. Then you just remove the element from the set.

Comment: Create a patient with that name, and remove it (assuming the badly named  nameComp is a comparator only comparing the name of patients). Methods start with a lowercase; classes start with an uppercase. You're doing the  reverse. But I have the feeling that what you actually want is a Map<String, Patient>.

Comment: Hi JB Nizet, my nameComp is indeed my comparator to sort my Tree in ascending order base on the patient name. My add Patient function is working correctly but now i am stuck with the delete method base on the name given in the parameter.

Comment: @user7495150 As I said, you probably want a Map<String, Patient>. But if you really want to stick with your TreeSet, create a Patient with that name, and remove it from the set. Not sure how I can be clearer.

Comment: Since we're talking about sorting and `Map`s, I'm going to point out the [`SortedMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) (and its child [`NavigableMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html)) interface and its two implementations: [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) (not thread-safe) and [`ConcurrentSkipListMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) (thread-safe).

Comment: While both of the implementations mentioned above are both `SortedMap` and `NavigableMap`, using `NavigableMap` exposes the `descendingMap` function, which returns a view of the map sorted in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterating and removing while doing so, will result in a Concurrent Modification Exception. You could temp save the item to remove and remove it later:
For example:

```
void removePatient(String patientName) {
    Person deleteThat;
    for (Patient p : ts){
       if(p.getName().equals(patientName){
           deleteThat = p;
       }
    }
    if(deleteThat != null){
        ts.remove(deleteThat);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not if you use the `Iterator` manually (instead of a foreach loop) and call its `remove` method.

Comment: That's true. Still assume that this solution is easier.

Comment: Indeed using iterating causes Concurrent Modication Exception. Thanks Powerlord